# How to get current Build definition name using PowerShell in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, tfs

We are using TFSdeployer to trigger Build deployment to deploy build.

But stuck with how to get Build definition of the current Build for which we trying and could not succeed.

How to get current Build definition name using below PowerShell script instead of hardcode.

Scenario: If i trigger from Test1 BuildQuality then first code should be working . If i trigger from Test2 BuildQuality then second code should be working. (If-Else code is working perfectly)

Tried using $TFSDeployerBuildDetail.DefinitionName
$Build.Name

But that seems to be not working, Any help is appreciated.

```
$BuildDefinitionName =  "Test1"
$PackagePath = "C:\extra\Package_Files"
$DestPath1 ="C:\extra\Test1"
$DestPath2 ="C:\extra\Test2"
$logFile ="C:\extra\logs"
$utilPath = "C:\util\"


if ($BuildDefinitionName -eq "Test1")
{

Write-Host "Testing 1st Copy"

Add-Content -Path $logFile "Copying to Test1"
& $utilPath\robocopy $PackagePath $DestPath1 /s >> $logFile

}

elseif($BuildDefinitionName -eq "Test2")
{

Write-Host "Testing 2nd Copy"
Add-Content -Path $logFile "Copying to Test2"
& $utilPath\robocopy $PackagePath $DestPath2 /s >> $logFile

}
```

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? Are you using XAML builds or the web-based build system?

Comment: I'm using xaml based build and ms build combined with tfs deployer for build and deployment automation.

Answer (score 2):

Use the provided environment variable:

```
$env:BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/scripts/powershell

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Since you indicated you're using [XAML build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh850448%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), the environment variable would be `$env:TF_BUILD_BUILDDEFINITIONNAME`.

The other answer is correct for the newer, web-based build system.

Comment: Thanks how do i save it to variables?

Comment: @JohnZachariah Why do you want to save it to variables? It's the predefined variable, you can use it directly.